# Finding seven disjoint seven element subsets of $\{1,2, ..., 49\}$ with same sum

Tags: combinatorics, latin-square

I have a set containing numbers $1$ to $49: \{1,2,3, \cdots, 49\}$.

Now, I want to divide the set into $7$ subsets such that each subset should contain $7$ elements and sum of the elements of each subset should be $175$.

Is it possible to prove that such subsets exist?

Comment: I retagged this to combinatorics, which is the appropriate tag I believe.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lookup [Magic Squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square).

which has the following:

```
22  47  16  41  10  35  4
5    23  48  17  42  11  29
30  6   24  49  18  36  12
13  31  7   25  43  19  37
38  14  32  1   26  44  20
21  39  8   33  2   27  45
46  15  40  9   34  3   28
```

Answer (score 7):

Magic squares are fine, but here any single 7x7 Latin square works. An $n\times n$ Latin square is a square with the property that all the integers $1\ldots n$ appear exactly once
on each row and column. There are several ways of constructing these. When $n=7$ we have for example the following
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
7&1&2&3&4&5&6\\
6&7&1&2&3&4&5\\
5&6&7&1&2&3&4\\
4&5&6&7&1&2&3\\
3&4&5&6&7&1&2\\
2&3&4&5&6&7&1\\
\end{array}
$$

Given an $n\times n$ Latin square we can construct a solution to this problem (or its generalization of partitioning the integers $\{1,2,\ldots,n^2\}$ into $n$ equal sum groups of $n$ each) as follows.

Add $n(i-1)$ to all the entries on row $\#i$. After that the sum of the entries on any column equals $\sum_{i=1}^ni+ n\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(i-1)\right)$, which is manifestly independent of the column. Furthermore, the integer $n(i-1)+j$, $1\le i,j\le n$, can only appear on row $\#i$, and does occur there exactly once (wherevere the entry $j$ of that row of the Latin square resides). The above 7x7 Latin square gives rise to the groups
$$\{1,7+7=14,6+14=20,5+21=26,4+28=32,3+35=38,2+42=44\}$$ from the first column, $\{2,8,21,27,33,39,45\}$ from the second, $\{3,9,15,28,34,40,46\}$ from the third column,
and so forth.

It is also possible to construct magic squares from Latin squares, but then you need richer structure. You need two so called [mutually ortogonal Latin squares](https://planetmath.org/OrthogonalLatinSquares) (=MOLS).